# Unspecified media query

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries, responsiveness

I have used a media query to hide an element when the screen size decreases. I set max-width to 780px.

`@media only screen and (max-width: 780px) {

```
/* the container for #left and #right elements */
.container { 
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: auto;
}

/* the element to be hidden */
#left {
  display: none;
}

/* this element should then take up the whole width of the container */
#right {
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  border-radius: 2%;
}
```

}`

It behaves as per the media query only at about 770px and below.

I have also included bootstrap classes **col-sm-12 col-md-6** for #right.

Between 780px and 770px, #left gets hidden but the #right does not occupy the full space of .container. Instead, #right takes up the first half space of .container, where #left should be and the original space of #right is unoccupied.

What is this unwanted gap and how do I eliminate it?

Answer (score 0):

There are two things `min-width` and `max-width` and it functions as
if you use `(min-width:768)` it means that the design will be applied to the screen width greater than 768px, i-e: from 768px - infinity.
if you use `(max-width:768)` it means that the design will be applied to the screen width less than 768px, i-e: from 0 - 767px.

Coming back to your question.

```
.container { 
width: 300px;
height: 400px;
overflow: auto;
}
```

Here you are specifying the width of container as 300px, change it as

```
.container { 
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    overflow: auto;
    }
```

Similarly,

```
#right {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  border-radius: 2%;
}
```

Please let me know If it helps.

Comment: I don't want the container class to take up 100% width. I want #right, which is inside .container, to occupy the whole of .container. 

Also, it behaves like I want it to only at 580px and lower, not from 780px as I have specified.

Comment: then use right to 100% and container to 300px, secondly your max-width 580px;

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the width to 100% and it should work.

```
#right {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  border-radius: 2%;
}
```

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work. It expands but does not occupy the whole space. I am unable to figure out which container it expands with respect to. 

I have also given #right a bootstrap class of col-sm-6. Has this got anything to do with that?

Comment: **Update:** I changed my bootstrap classes to  "col-sm-12 col-md-6" and now the problem is only between 770px and 780px